# Laravel Bootstrap Sidebar Active Menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sidebar

I'm creating sidebar using bootstrap css at my laravel project with `<ul>` html tag like this

```
<?php $segment1 = Request::segment(1); ?>
<li class="{!! $segment1 == 'a3' ? 'active':'' !!}">
  <a href="{!! route('a3.index') !!}">
      <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>a3</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

The URL is

```
localhost:8000/a3
```

That's why I'm using segment 1, I'm trying to change my route prefix to admin so the URL become like this

```
localhost:8000/admin/a3
```

So I must change the sidebar code every single li become segment 3

And my question is, is there a way to code sidebar better than I do so when I change my prefix I don't need to change the segment too?

Answer (score 0):

Try to match with a pattern instead, for example:

```
Request::is('*/a3');
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests